# Can I disable MDS on a single web part page

Tags: javascript, cewp, mds, minimal-download-strategy

I have a custom list on a custom web part page with scripts that affect color coding as well as clickable attachment icons.

These scripts do not execute when the list is grouped, and the groups are set to collapse on page load. The scripts do work when the list is grouped but the groups are set to expand on page load. From my understanding this is to Minimal Download Strategy MDS (when expanding an already loaded collapsed group, the list is loaded after the script executed, so it does not execute on the list).

I cannot use PowerShell. I cannot use Designer. I cannot change the master page. I cannot use Site Maintenance/Site Settings etc. These are all features that have been disabled for us.

I have to be able to do this using a Script Editor Web Part or Content Editor Web Part.

Is it possible to disable MDS on a single specific web part page this way? Or is there a way for my scripts and javascripts to execute even while MDS is enabled?

I have done research on this but I am simply not completely understanding what I am reading. I am saddened to say that I need someone to dumb it down on how to apply any SharePoint:scriptlink tags or anything else in a SEWP or CEWP.

Side note when attempting to post this...how is SEWP not a Tag in a SharePoint blog post...

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your groups to be expanded or collapsed by default? Note that expanding or collapsing happens dynamically, so when the group is collapsed and you try to "select" elements inside that group, they are not available until you expand the group, so these elements are loaded dynamically through JavaScript. If you want to apply your scripts to the groups while they are expanded, why not expand the groups by default? You can even use the jQuery.ready to make sure the page itself was loaded then execute your scripts.

For the MDS, it's a site feature thing, so it's either activated on the site or not, it's not a functionality per page, it makes sure you send the minimum amount of data to the server when navigating from one page to another.

Comment: Yes. I understand why the scrupts dont execut on a collapsed grouped list. I have set the default to expanded groups but its just too much data, everything ends up needing to be collapsed by each user and its just plain unappealing. I need a workaround through CEWP or SEWP. I don't know much about jQuery, but I believe that is a 3rd party program that needs to be downloaded correct? If so I can't use that either. If not maybe you can help me understand how to apply and executive jQuery.

Comment: Can you let me know more what your styles do? What do they style exactly?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot will be great.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the .js files that are being referenced.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the .js files that are being referenced. In Regards to Styles I recently discovered: If my list is set to Default Style the above scenario is true. If I change my Style to Shaded, then my clickable attachment icon will work grouped or un-grouped, collapsed or expanded. The only Style my color coding works in is Default Style and without grouping. What specifically would you like screen shots of?

Comment: If you can provide screenshots of what's going on it would be better to have a better understanding.